# How much time paypal takes to complete transaction

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I am integrating PayPal in my iOS app.

I don't have any idea about what time its take complete the transaction.

Means if a customer has made a purchase then after how much time the certain amount is deducted from customer's account and transferred to mine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instant. The money is in your PayPal account before PayPal responds to the API call. (Presuming you request instant payments, that is, instead of just placing an order or auth etc.)